# YouTube jsapi video card

Tags: javascript, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, youtube-channels

Is there a way through the JS api for YouTube embeds to make the end of a video show to users subscribe / about card. I've searched high and low and can't seem to find any ways of doing so. Any other solutions outside of the JS api? Maybe adding or replication with DOM or other method? Thanks!

**EXAMPLE:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/ivtcxnbszrylwzi/Screenshot%202014-04-09%2015.53.21.png

Answer (score 0):

One possibility, if you were to use the iFrame API, would be to bind to the playerStateChange events and listen for the YT.PlayerState.ENDED event ... and when you hear it, you replace the video with your subscribe button. Some sort of setup like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="myPlayer"></div>
<script>
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
  player = new YT.Player(document.getElementById("myPlayer"), {
    width: "853",
    height: "480",
    videoId: "f3_JLyVgbEA",
    events: {
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    // here's where you replace the video with your subscribe button
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```